# Redirection of STDOUT and STDERR in sh script fails

Tags: linux, sh, stderr

I'm trying to redirect ALL output from the shell script that starts my Python program from a service. STDERR still ends up in syslog and not in the logfile. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/sh
TODAY="$(date --date='today' +\%F)"
LOGFILE="/home/pi/log/otgw/$TODAY.heating3.log"
OUTPUT="2>&1 >>$LOGFILE"  # direct LOG, STDOUT, STDERR to the logfile
COMMAND="/home/pi/live/otgw/heating3.py --anti_pendle_enabled --extend_heating --program_selector war  -tcd -d --loglevel monitor --logfile $LOGFILE"
eval "$COMMAND $OUTPUT"
```

Comment: Does `OUTPUT=">>$LOGFILE 2>&1"` work?

Comment: (OT: Putting a command in a variable and `eval`ing it is notoriously fragile. Any particular reason you don’t simply run the command?)

Comment: I can't easily test this as the script is invoked from a service; I will write a dummy service and program to test and report back. I need to ensure that invocation from a service is not the cause of the problem).

Comment: The proposed solution (OUTPUT=">>$LOGFILE 2>&1") works. Can anyone explain why the original solution did not work and this one does?